# AWS EC2 client/server can't communicate via Node HTTP server

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, client-server

I have two AWS EC2 instanses. A Server and a client Node JS app.

Locally my code is working fine.
But at AWS the client simply shuts down after some time - like 30 sec - without any warning/exception (For some reason it can't find and connect to the server)

Both AWS instances are running: Windows Server 2016 Base.

Both AWS instance have their own sererate "AWS security group". Just to make sure i'm not blocking any thing both security groups currently allow: 
"All traffic to ANY IP" - both Ingoing and Outgoing traffic.

Both instances run in the same "Availability zone" in AWS.

The server is listening at host: '0.0.0.0', port: 4080.
And the client tries to connect to the server's IP at port 4080. I have tried to connect to all possible options - like:

1. Public DNS (IPv4)
2. IPv4 Public IP
3. Elastic IP
4. Private IPs

I can't even ping the server's IP from the client or from my own PC. I can access both AWS instances fine via RDP.

Here is a bit of my code:

### SERVER.JS

```
var server = require('http').createServer();
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;

var wss = new WebSocketServer({ server: server });

server.on('request', app);
server.listen(_port, '0.0.0.0', function () { console.log('SERVER STARTED! (listening on port # ' + _port + ')') });
```

### CLIENT.JS

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var _ws = new WebSocket(THE_SERVER_IP);

_ws.on('open', function open() {

            ...
        });

        _ws.on('message', function (data, flags) {

            ...
        });

        _ws.on('close', function close() {
            ...
        });
```

Comment: Are you sure you allowed all TCP traffic in and out? for all ports?

Comment: Yes, all ports, all protocols, any IP - on both security groups

Comment: are you running on Linux? http://serverfault.com/questions/301903/cannot-access-port-80-from-remote-location-but-works-on-local

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that! No - both AWS instances are running Windows Server 2016 Base.

Comment: I just realized - when i disable the Windows Firewall for both Client and Server - it all works! Why do i need to set both Windows Firewall rules and AWS "Security Group" rules? I guess it then need to create the same entries in the firewall as in the "Security group" - right?

Comment: AWS Security Group rules are configuring AWS firewall rules, you still need to configure Windows Firewall if indeed you are using it. You could conceivably turn it off and rely on AWS firewall, after all you are just duplicating the same rules.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I added a custom TCP rule to the Windows Firewall in the server where my server.js app is running - which allow the client's IP to connect to port 4080. Done.